# How do i display all users profile pictures in template

Tags: python, django

I have been able to add an image field in Profile, and also i created users and attached an image to all my users profile. Now, how do i display all users profile pictures in template. I try this: profile_img = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id) but it display the current login user profile picture in all users profile picture. I want to display all profile pictures for each user in template.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', blank=True)

def home(request):
    profile_img = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id) 
    print(profile_img)
    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)

{% for user in users %}
<div class="row mb-2">
    {% for profile in profile_img %}
    {% if profile.profile_pic %}
      <a href="{% url 'site:profile' user.username %}">  
      <img src="{{ profile.profile_pic.url }}" class="rounded-circle avatar-img z-depth-1-half mb-3 mt-1" height="55" width="55" style="border:none;padding:0px;">
      </a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def home(request):
    profile_img = Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    print(profile_img)`

```
<div class="row mb-2">
{% for profile in profile_img %}
{% if profile.profile_pic %}
  <a href="{% url 'site:profile' user.username %}">  
  <img src="{{ profile.profile_pic.url }}" class="rounded-circle avatar-img z-depth-1-half mb-3 mt-1" height="55" width="55" style="border:none;padding:0px;">
  </a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I think no need to add a for loop of user because you are excluding a current user and saving other two objects in a variable named **users** so that it will loop twice and print the same thing again avoid that for loop of users. You should get the images only once

Comment: @Gokulaselvan..users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id) display all the list of users in template. If I do not add a loop for user in users how can I get all the list of users in template? And also if I remove loop for user then I have a problem of creating a href link to users profile page. Do you have any suggestions on how I can handle this?

Comment: @GistDomBlog you dont need to create user variable you can directly use exclude in profile_img as i mentioned in the answer.That profile_img already having the two objects which are except the current user. Now with the profile_img for loop you will get the profile pic of each objects in the if statement........ So try once try the code with the above

Comment: Your code works correctly, it only display a user with a profile picture. This is nice. But the problem now is that url do not reverse to other user page. When I loop for user in users, I use this url 'site:profile' user.username but now I use loop for profile in profile_img, I change my url to 'site:profile' profile.username this does not redirect me to profile, it display reverse for profile with keyword arguments {'username' } not found. I'm using username not an ID in url.

Comment: @GistDomBlog try using 'site:profile' user.id and add get_absolute_url in the models.py this might solve the url do not reverse or use primary key (pk) in the model instead of id

Comment: @Gokulaselvan..this 'site:profile' user.id donot take me to other users profile page, it only redirect me to the logged in user profile page(user who is logged in) . What I mean is that I want to click a link that will take me to other users profile page. Do I have to create a separate user profile page for all users?

Comment: @GistDomBlog make a new question on it add with the codes from all the main files in django.....

Comment: @Gokulaselvan...I have found the solution, the link wasn't working because the href is inside the endif loop. When I put the href outside the endif loop it worked. It was a mistake on my path on template format. Thank you for your time, I learnt a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, In views you are filtering it by `request.user.id` ( This is like you want to send only the users profile pic based on user-id). instead try `Profile.objects.all()`.( This will send all the images of profiles in it)

If you want to make it in order use `Profile.objects.all().order_by('-id')`.This will order it by user id.

want to exclude the current users image use an to display all the images

```
Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
```

Comment: @Gokulaselvan...Thanks you are right, I have also implemented such, but the problem is that the login user profile picture still display on the list. How do I exclude only the login user profile picture? For example, I have 3 users(John, Mike, Paul). When John is logged in, I do not want John's profile picture to display, only Mike and Paul.

Comment: Then use Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).This might give you the expected results as excluding the current user id and display all the images

Comment: Why do users profile picture display like this: (Mike img, Paul img)  (Paul img, Mike img). Instead of (Mike img, Paul img). Should this be the cause of the template code? or distinct() should be the best way to Handel this?

Comment: @GistDomBlog share the code which you have added and output. I am unable to visualize

Comment: i have updated my question, by adding the code of template.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from User. In my views I have: users=User objects.exclude(id=request.user.id) this is returning a user twice in template. How can I return a user just once in template?